# How refresh "Unit Test Sessions" results in ReSharper? (sticky failed test)

Tags: resharper

From time to time, the ReSharper "Unit Test Sessions" window will have a "sticky" test that fails to clear from failed to succeeded after the test has been fixed.  A right-click "Create New Session" for the failed test yields 0 tests in the new session (further evidence that something is off).  Is there a way to force a refresh for the test (clearing the red failure) without having to re-run all tests?

"Repeat Previous Run" does not do it.  If I right-click the unit test *in source code* and create a new session, the test will pass.

JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3.2
Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.6.5

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clear Test Result** menu item visible on your second screenshot does exactly that - drops saved test result for the current session.

However, could you report the issue into JetBrains bug tracker and provide a sample (together with ReSharper caches) the next time test result is stuck?

Comment: Yes, will do. However, the symptom is no longer occurring.  My delay in replying was to give it a few days.